# How to install Bangla font in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, fonts

I'm trying to install Bangla font in Ubuntu but I'm struggling. I have downloaded `SolaimanLipi_20-04-07.ttf` font & saved it on my Desktop. I'm trying to copy the file to the right location but it's not working:

```
$ sudo cp -r /home/Desktop/SolaimanLipi_20-04-07.ttf /usr/share/fonts/truetype
cp: cannot stat '/home/Desktop/SolaimanLipi_20-04-07.ttf': No such file or directory
```

Also tried to copy but I got this error:

```
opening file '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/SolaimanLipi_20-04-07.ttf': Permission denied
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: just use `cp ~/Desktop/SolaimanLipi_20-04-07.ttf ~/.local/share/fonts/`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing you should try is to install the `fonts-beng` package from the Ubuntu archive:

```
sudo apt install fonts-beng
```

That package installs the *Lohit Bengali* font.

Comment: OP wanted to install a specific font

Comment: @Anwar: Well, he asked how to install a Bangla font, and let us know what he had tried. I assumed that he wasn't aware of the fact that a Bangla font is easily available in the archive, and my assumption seems to have been correct. ;)

Comment: Ubuntu used to include bengali by default. I haven't used ubuntu iso to install, instead used kubuntu and it has the bengali font. However, it seems Ubuntu dropped them in default

Comment: @Anwar: I don't see it in Kubuntu's list of default fonts either, but it's included in the Bangla language support. Anyway, this explains why we interpreted the question differently.

Comment: It's Noto Font Bengali. I checked the ISO. Also previously Ubuntu used to include Bangla font. I believe ttf-indic-core-fonts package from [trusty](http://releases.ubuntu.com/trusty/ubuntu-14.04.4-desktop-i386.manifest) does the job

Comment: @Anwar: Hmm.. `ttf-indic-core-fonts` is replaced with `fonts-indic` nowadays, and yes, it's not shipped by Ubuntu. Maybe that was a mistake...

Comment: @Anwar: In Ubuntu 17.10 `fonts-indic` is installed by default.

Answer (score 4):

`/home/Desktop/`  is not a correct (default) directory. It should be `/home/$USER/Desktop/`.

The 2nd problem is due to not using `sudo` or not using a session started with `sudo -i`. Your "normal" user account isn't allowed to write to the directory `/usr/share/fonts/truetype`, so you need root permissions to copy the file.

Comment: where do I use sudo -i ? Is it instead of sudo cp -r ?

Comment: `sudo` (*s*witch *u*ser and *do*) executes one command as another user. If you don't specify the user,  `root` is assumed. So, `sudo cp -r something /to/somewhere` means "switch to 'root' and execute 'cp -r something /to/somwhere'". With `sudo -i` (no command added) you can open a new interactive shell session for the other user, in this case "root".

Answer (score 1):

I've put commonly used fonts in a [git repo](https://github.com/hmoazzem/bangla-fonts). If you have git installed, issue the below command:

```
git clone https://github.com/hmoazzem/bangla-fonts.git; mkdir $HOME/.fonts/; cp -r bangla-fonts $HOME/.fonts/; fc-cache -f -v
```

This should install the fonts.

Answer (score 1):

Manual installation process

1. Download all Bangla font from https://github.com/bulbul5391/all_bangla_font
2. Now go to /usr/local/share/fonts directory and create the "sample" folder

   ```
   sudo mkdir sample
   sudo chmod -R 777 sample
   ```
3. After that copy all bangla fonts not folder and past in sample folder
4. Then close browser and open browser

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is paste the font into .fonts folder in Home folder. If .fonts folder does not exists ( it is normally hidden, try CTRL + H ), you need to create one.

You can also use Google's Noto fonts from here

https://www.google.com/get/noto/#sans-beng

Comment: Noto font is available in ubuntu repository and OP can just install `fonts-noto` package

Answer (score 0):

checkout the link for details:
https://fahadahammed.com/single-command-to-download-and-install-all-bangla-fonts-in-your-linux/

```
$ pip3 install --upgrade lbfi
$ lbfi --install yes
```

If it doesn’t work, try below one:

```
$ wget --no-check-certificate https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fahadahammed/linux-bangla-fonts/master/font.sh -O font.sh;chmod +x font.sh;bash font.sh;rm font.sh
```

If it also doesn’t work, try below one:

```
$ wget --no-check-certificate https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fahadahammed/linux-bangla-fonts/master/dist/lbfi -O lbfi;chmod +x lbfi;./lbfi
```